# Why do i have to initialize an array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, initialization

So why do i have to do this "People[city][years]**=1000**;" thing?

```
int People[2059][100];
for (int city = 0; city < 2059; city++)
for (int years = 0; years < 100; years++)
People[city][years] = 1000;
```

Comment: If you don't initialize variables, they will contain random values. If you don't care about this, you don't have to initialize your array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Uninitialized non-static local (a.k.a. "automatic") variables will have an *indeterminate* value. Using them even to read their value will lead to *undefined behavior* in C++. In C it's legal to read their value unless it's a trap-value.

Comment: On an unrelated note, your array will be 823600 bytes large. Local variables are usually stored on the stack, and the stack is a limited resource. For example the default Windows process stack is a single megabyte. Your array is close to push the limit of that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude *"even to read their values"* - makes it sound a bit like writing into them is UB as well.

Comment: Oh, and if you want to initialize all elements to zero there's a very simple way to do that: `int People[X][Y] = {};`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude-- AFIK this works in C++, but it needs to be `People[X][Y] = { 0 };` in C.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to. But then the `People` array will contain indeterminate values, and reading them makes for a program with undefined behavior (I'm assuming that it's a variable with automatic storage duration). That's not an overly useful program.

If the array has static storage duration, then it will be zero-initialized. If you are okay with that, you don't have to loop over it and assign values immediately.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
People[city][years] = 1000;
```

initializes the values in your 2D array to `1000` on the stack. If you don't initialize the numbers in your array, they can be anything.

Instead, you can initialize the numbers in `People` to `0`:

```
int People[2059][100] = {{0}}; /* or 1000, if you prefer that */
```

Using this instead saves you having to loop over the array and assign every value to `0`. If you decide to insert other numbers, then initializing the array won't be needed.